# How does a 'diff' algorithm work, e.g. in VCDIFF and DiffMerge?

Tags: algorithm, diff, vcdiff

I've been looking like crazy for an explanation of a diff algorithm that works and is efficient.

The closest I got is [this link to RFC 3284](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3284.html) (from several Eric Sink blog posts), which describes in perfectly understandable terms the *data format* in which the diff results are stored. However, it has no mention whatsoever as to how a program would reach these results while doing a diff.

I'm trying to research this out of personal curiosity, because I'm sure there must be tradeoffs when implementing a diff algorithm, which are pretty clear sometimes when you look at diffs and wonder "why did the diff program chose this as a change instead of that?"...

Where can I find a description of an efficient algorithm that'd end up outputting VCDIFF?
By the way, if you happen to find a description of the actual algorithm used by SourceGear's DiffMerge, that'd be even better.

Note: longest common subsequence doesn't seem to be the algorithm used by VCDIFF. It looks like they're doing something smarter, given the data format they use.

Comment: Nothing on wikipedia ? You can maybe try to find another implementation in a hight level langage like python, that might be easier to understand than a C implementation. Python is famous for being easily readable ? There's a difflib in python. Here's the url to the source. The source has tons of comments about diff algorithms.
http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/difflib.py?revision=69846&view=markup

Comment: RFCs are not meant to describe algorithms. They are meant to describe interfaces(/protocols).

Comment: Actually, the core of the diff algorithm, the longest common sub-sequence problem, can be found on Wikipedia. This page gives an overview of the algorithm and sample code that I found helpful when I needed to write a custom diff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://paulbutler.org/archives/a-simple-diff-algorithm-in-php/ It sure is awesome, and it's so small (only **29 lines altogether**; it has 2 functions). It's similar to Stack Overflow's edit revision compare thing.

Comment: VCDIFF is not for human readable diffs. It employs add, copy and run instructions as opposed to the more human readable delete and insert instructions emitted by most plain text diff algorithms. For VCDIFF you need something like the xdelta algortihm described here http://www.xmailserver.org/xdfs.pdf

Comment: [Here is C# implementation.](https://github.com/Harmyder/Differ) It includes lots of unit tests. As a bonus it has a highlighter, so you can prepare data to show diff in the UI. It also has a web project that you can run and test how it works interactively.

Comment: My daily reminded of when stackoverflow closes important and popular questions.

Comment: some popular ones are enumerated in this config for the popular software Beyond Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990289/1330381

Answer (score 199, accepted):

*[An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations (1986, Eugene W. Myers)](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf)* is a fantastic paper and you may want to start there. It includes pseudo-code and a nice visualization of the graph traversals involved in doing the diff.

**Section 4** of the paper introduces some refinements to the algorithm that make it very effective.

Successfully implementing this will leave you with a very useful tool in your toolbox (and probably some excellent experience as well).

Generating the output format you need can sometimes be tricky, but if you have understanding of the algorithm internals, then you should be able to output anything you need. You can also introduce heuristics to affect the output and make certain tradeoffs.

[Here is a page](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/) that includes a bit of documentation, [full source code](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/ViewSrc.aspx), and examples of a diff algorithm using the techniques in the aforementioned algorithm.

The [source code](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/ViewSrc.aspx) appears to follow the basic algorithm closely and is easy to read.

There's also a bit on preparing the input, which you may find useful. There's a huge difference in output when you are diffing by character or token (word).

Comment: In case the link goes bad, this is Myers 1986; see e.g. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6927 -- it further includes a link to the Unix `diff` paper by Hunt and McIlroy.

Comment: The link did indeed go bad, so I've changed it to ^ (where I've verified the paper is still available for download as of August 2022) and added the author and date to the body of the answer as well.

Answer (score 36):

I would begin by looking at the actual  *source code* for diff, which GNU makes [available](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/).

For an *understanding* of how that source code actually works, the docs in that package reference the papers that inspired it:

> The basic algorithm is described in "An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations", Eugene W. Myers, 'Algorithmica' Vol. 1 No. 2, 1986, pp. 251-266; and in "A File
>   Comparison Program", Webb Miller and Eugene W. Myers, 'Software--Practice and Experience' Vol. 15 No. 11, 1985, pp. 1025-1040. The algorithm was independently discovered as described in "Algorithms for Approximate String Matching", E. Ukkonen, `Information and Control' Vol. 64, 1985, pp. 100-118.

Reading the papers then looking at the source code for an implementation should be more than enough to understand how it works.

Comment: Hmmm, in short, sometimes figuring out the underlying algorithm from actual source code (especially if it's optimized to be efficient) can be quite complex. I will be able to understand what the program is doing step by step, but not exactly "why", or a high level overview about that...
Example: You'd never understand how regular expressions work (or what they are) by looking at the implementation of Perl's Regexes. Or if you could do that, then I tip my hat, I definitely need a more explained, higher level overview to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I never understand how the vast majority of Perl works :-), but there's a link in the package docs (see update) that will point you to the literature describing it (it being the diff algorithm, not Perl).

Comment: Don't read the code.  Read the paper.

Comment: Two other sources are mentioned in the docs of that package:

- The algorithm was independently discovered as described by Esko Ukkonen in "Algorithms for
Approximate String Matching", ‘Information and Control’ Vol. 64, 1985,
pp. 100-118, <http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(85)80046-2>. 

- Related algorithms are surveyed by Alfred V. Aho in section 6.3 of "Algorithms
for Finding Patterns in Strings", ‘Handbook of Theoretical Computer
Science’ (Jan Van Leeuwen, ed.), Vol. A, ‘Algorithms and Complexity’,
Elsevier/MIT Press, 1990, pp. 255-300.

Answer (score 31):

See [Diff Match and Patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch)

> "The Diff Match and Patch libraries
> offer robust algorithms to perform the
> operations required for synchronizing
> plain text.  ... Currently available
> in Java, JavaScript, C++, C# and
> Python"

Also see the Wikipedia [Diff page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) and "[Bram Cohen: The diff problem has been solved](http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/37690.html)"

Comment: Just wanted to mention that Cohen's algorithm also seem's to be known as Patience Diff.  It's the (default?) diff algorithm in bazaar and an optional one in git.

Answer (score 13):

I came here looking for the diff algorithm and afterwards made my own implementation. Sorry I don't know about *vcdiff*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm): From a longest common subsequence, it's only a small step to get diff-like output: if an item is absent in the subsequence but present in the original, it must have been deleted. (The '–' marks, below.) If it is absent in the subsequence but present in the second sequence, it must have been added in. (The '+' marks.)

Nice animation of the [LCS algorithm here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence).

Link to a fast [LCS Ruby implementation here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Dynamic_programming.2C_walker_class).

My slow and simple Ruby adaptation is below.

```
def lcs(xs, ys)
  if xs.count > 0 and ys.count > 0
    xe, *xb = xs
    ye, *yb = ys
    if xe == ye
      return [xe] + lcs(xb, yb)
    end
    a = lcs(xs, yb)
    b = lcs(xb, ys)
    return (a.length > b.length) ? a : b
  end
  return []
end

def find_diffs(original, modified, subsequence)
  result = []
  while subsequence.length > 0
    sfirst, *subsequence = subsequence
    while modified.length > 0
      mfirst, *modified = modified
      break if mfirst == sfirst
      result << "+#{mfirst}"
    end
    while original.length > 0
      ofirst, *original = original
      break if ofirst == sfirst
      result << "-#{ofirst}"
    end
    result << "#{sfirst}"
  end
  while modified.length > 0
    mfirst, *modified = modified
    result << "+#{mfirst}"
  end
  while original.length > 0
    ofirst, *original = original
    result << "-#{ofirst}"
  end
  return result
end

def pretty_diff(original, modified)
  subsequence = lcs(modified, original)
  diffs = find_diffs(original, modified, subsequence)

  puts 'ORIG      [' + original.join(', ') + ']'
  puts 'MODIFIED  [' + modified.join(', ') + ']'
  puts 'LCS       [' + subsequence.join(', ') + ']'
  puts 'DIFFS     [' + diffs.join(', ') + ']'
end

pretty_diff("human".scan(/./), "chimpanzee".scan(/./))
# ORIG      [h, u, m, a, n]
# MODIFIED  [c, h, i, m, p, a, n, z, e, e]
# LCS       [h, m, a, n]
# DIFFS     [+c, h, +i, -u, m, +p, a, n, +z, +e, +e]
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on the link Emmelaich gave, there is also a great rundown of *diff strategies* on [Neil Fraser's website (one of the authors of the library)](http://neil.fraser.name/writing/diff/).

He covers basic strategies and towards the end of the article progresses to [Myers' algorithm](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/myers.pdf) and some graph theory.