# Finding the Difference between the contents in two Files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am developing a Application which takes two Files and output will be two files which will have only the contents which differs in both the files.

The application is developed using VC++
My Files are of Html type

Is there any library which will do the diff opereation between two files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/about/) is a Windows differencing and merging tool. It uses diffutils, written using VC++, and it's open source.

Comment: This was the most helpful tool and u can customize it according to ur  need

Answer (score 1):

You can probably easily link [diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) into your code.

Comment: It might well be just as easy to shell out to a diff command line if the environment permits.

Comment: He cannot link diffutils into his code unless he's building free software under GPL license.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what types of files you are comparing. Are they text? HTML? Binaries?

Try searching this site (and Google) for ['diff'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diff), there are lots of [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805626/diff-algorithm/1313218#1313218) ranging from general how-to, to code examples, to full source code and 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at a couple of CodeProject articles that could be modified to generate the diff files you require:

1) [Diff Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/difftool.aspx)

2) [V Diff](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/vdiff.aspx) - A File Comparer with visual output