# Comparing file contents in Python

Tags: python

I have two files, say source and target. I compare each element in source to check if it also exists in target. If it does not exist in target, I print it ( the end goal is to have 0 difference). Here is the code I have written.

```
def finddefaulters(source,target):
  f = open(source,'r')
  g = open(target,'r')

  reference = f.readlines()
  done = g.readlines()
  for i in reference:
    if i not in done:
      print i,
```

I need help with

1. How would this code be rated on a scale of 1-10
2. How can I make it better and optimal if the file sizes are huge.

Another question - When I read all the lines as list elements, they are interpreted as 'element\n' - So for correct comparison, I have to add a newline at the end of each file. Is there a way to strip the newlines so I do not have to add newline at the end of files. I tried rstrip. But it did not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `done = g.readlines()` creates a list. `if i not in done` searches in the list. Many times. Have a look at `set()`.

Comment: You appear to be reinventing [diff](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

Comment: Aside from all else, "f" and "g" are terrible names for your variables. Call them something sensible. "i" could also be improved.

Comment: For an efficient diff implementation, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805626/diff-algorithm/1338807#1338807

Comment: To improve your question, change the title to something sensible and I'll revoke my downvote.

Comment: @Kimvais - with >3k rep, you could just edit it.

Comment: The first 2 questions are probably better asked on codereview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding **efficiency**: The method you show has an [asymptotic runtime complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of `O(m*n)` where `m` and `n` are the number of elements in `reference` and `done`, i.e. if you double the size of both lists, the algorithm will run 4 times longer (times a fixed constant that is uniteresting to theoretical computer scientists). If `m` and `n` are very large, you will probably want to choose a faster algorithm, e.g sort the two lists first using the `.sort()` (runtime complexity: `O(n * log(n))`) and then go through the lists just once (runtime complexity: `O(n)`). That algorithm has a worst-case runtime complexity of `O(n * log(n))`, which is already a big improvement. However, you trade readability and simplicity of the code for efficiency, so I would only advise you to do this if absolutely necessary.

Regarding **coding style**: You do not `.close()` the file handles which you should. Instead of opening and closing the file handle, you could use the [`with` language construct](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) of python. Also, if you like the functional style, you could replace the for loop by a list expression:

```
for i in reference:
    if i not in done:
        print i,
```

then becomes:

```
items = [i.strip() for i in reference if i not in done]
print ' '.join(items)
```

However, this way you will not see any progress while the list is being composed.

As joaquin already mentions, you can loop over `f` directly instead of `f.readlines()` as file handles support the [iterator protocol](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/).

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

1) use [`[with]`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to open files safely:

```
with open(source) as f:
     .............
```

> The with statement is used to wrap the
>   execution of a block with methods
>   defined by a context manager. This
>   allows common try...except...finally
>   usage patterns to be encapsulated for
>   convenient reuse.

2) you can iterate over the lines of a file instead of using readlines:

```
for line in f:
     ..........
```

3) Although for this short snippet it could be enough, try to use more informative names for your variables. One-letter names are not recommended.

4) If you want to get profit of python lib, try functions in [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module. For example:

```
make_file(fromlines, tolines[, fromdesc][, todesc][, context][, numlines])
```

> Compares fromlines and tolines (lists
>   of strings) and returns a string which
>   is a complete HTML file containing a
>   table showing line by line differences
>   with inter-line and intra-line changes
>   highlighted.

Comment: You could provide a link to the with keyword docs, or explain what it does.