# Comparing Sentences in Java

Tags: java, string, compare

I would like to compare two sentences (sentences A and B), such that the program would output the changes made on sentence B from sentence A. For example:

sentence A: `It's a lovely day today.`
sentence B: `It's a very lovely day today, isnt it?`

Output: `It's a [I:very] lovely day today [C:./,] [I:isnt it?]`

where:
        `I` = INSERTED,
        `C` = CHANGED

PS: I havent started coding yet since I want to gather some of your ideas on how to best implement this case.

Comment: I'd start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: You will have to code it on your own... Start with link referenced in the first comment.

Comment: @GregHewgill I guess it's more like edit-distance problem. Isn't it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: @Nishant the edit distance is just a numeric value describing how different two strings are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diff Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805626/diff-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with below code and for this problem.

**Conditions Not considered**

1. Removed items from any of the list
2. First char difference
3. duplication of diff item

Please check and let me know if you have doubts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "It's a lovely day today.";
    String str2 = "It's a very lovely day today, isnt it?";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder added = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder changed = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                if (added.length() > 0) {
                    builder.append("[I:" + added.toString() + "]");
                    added = new StringBuilder();
                }
                if (changed.length() > 0) {
                    changed.append("[C:" + changed.toString() + "]");
                    changed = new StringBuilder();
                }
                // skip as there is no difference.
                builder.append(str1.charAt(i));
                i++;
                // check if index -1 chars are equal then there is
                // difference start
            } else if (str1.charAt(i - 1) == str2.charAt(j - 1)) {

                // check if end of line
                if ((i + 1 == str1.length())
                        || (str1.charAt(i + 1) == str2.charAt(j + 1))) {

                    changed.append(str1.charAt(i));
                    changed.append("/");
                    changed.append(str2.charAt(j));
                    j++;
                    // everything is added
                    if (i + 1 == str1.length()) {
                        while (j < str2.length() - 1)
                            added.append(str2.charAt(j++));
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                // Go until next equal found
                while (!(str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j))
                        && j < str2.length() - 1) {
                    added.append(str2.charAt(j++));
                }
                j--;

            }
        }
    if (changed.length() > 0) {
        builder.append("[C:" + changed.toString() + "]");
    }
    if (added.length() > 0) {
        builder.append("[I:" + added.toString() + "]");
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());

}
```

Output

```
It's a [I:very ]lovely day today[C:./,][I: isnt it]
```

Comment: Hey, this is working great! Thanks! Will there be a huge modification if I include the deletion of words, ie the output will also notify us for those words that were deleted in sentence B?

Comment: Finding character removal is easy finding word removal is tricky. You can find removal the same way I find Insertion but this time outer loop will be on Second string and inner loop will be on first string.

Comment: So if I include the deletion of words, I would have to do another nested looping aside from the loop above?