# How does the Beyond Compare diff algorithm work?

Tags: compare, diff, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I'm curious to know how does the diff algorithm of 'Beyond Compare' work?

I guess there's a standard (well-known?) diff algorithm they used to implement the "character .vs. character" comparison. Do you know the name of this diff algorithm? Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Beyond Compare uses a number of different algorithms depending on the file type and configuration.  In v4 the line alignment algorithms are explicitly named in the interface:

- Standard alignment - This is a proprietary algorithm; we haven't made the details publicly available.
- Myers O(ND) alignment - This is the same one that the GNU `diff` utility and most other applications use.  It's based on the paper "An O(ND) difference algorithm and its variations" by Eugene Myers (1986).
- Patience Diff alignment - This is the "Patience Diff" algorithm that Bram Cohen originally developed for Bazaar, which he talks about [here](https://bramcohen.livejournal.com/73318.html).

The character alignment to highlight differences within lines is based on the Myers O(ND) algorithm with some post-processing to clean up the results.

The alignment setting can be configured by clicking the Rules button [image: Beyond Compare rules button]

which brings up this dialog, which you can then configure for session scope or with a persistent default against the file association.

[image: Beyond Compare alignment settings]