# Kotlin. Simultaneously read from 2 files

Tags: file, kotlin, readfile

I need to read from 2 files and compare their content line by line. So I need something like `file.readNextLine()` functionality. How can I achieve that in Kotlin?

Edit:
Both files are already sorted. Some lines are absent in first file, some lines are absent in second file. I need to find this difference.

Comment: @Roland I edited question

Comment: thanks for your update. If you wouldn't have written that you are looking for differences I would have suggested you to use `zip` here... but now... did you try something already?

Answer (score 1):

Difference between files is a hard topic in general, but it depends on what kind of difference you'd like to spot. For example, a minimal difference? Or, maybe, it will be OK for you to report N-1 lines change if the only first line is missing?
A `diff` tool solves that. You may check a related thread on that:
[Diff Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805626/diff-algorithm)

```
    File("a").useLines { a ->
      File("b").useLines { b -> 

        val aIt = a.iterator()
        val bIt = b.iterator()

        //Do the DIFF on iterators
      }
    }
```

The code reads files in Kotlin in a line-by-line lazy fashion (using sequences). Next, you may use iterators to implement the diff algorithm.